# I can't use parseInt on JSON data from redis?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, redis

So I have been having issues with redis. I've only recently started learning how to use it but basically, I know how to send JSON, and get JSON. Which is all I need. Now the issue is that when I try and parseInt the json data I get nothing. It's just 0. When I used fs with a json file. I didn't even need to parseInt, but with redis I can't do anything with the JSON I receive. So I want to ask. How can I send data, call for it, then turn it into numbers I can use to make calculations. I should also mention I have tried sending int values in keys but that also didn't work. I will leave some snippets of code that I used to test redis.

```js
function logvalues() {
    redisClient.set("industrial", redisdatabase.industrial, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(`New average values logged, industrial: ${redisdatabase.industrial}`);
        }
    });
    redisClient.set("milspec", JSON.stringify(redisdatabase), (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(`New average values logged, milspec: ${redisdatabase.milspec}`);
            redisClient.get("milspec", (err, reply) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                } else {
                    console.log(reply);
                    reply = JSON.parse(reply);
                    var milspecvalue = reply.milspec.valueOf();
                    console.log(milspecvalue)
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

also, here are some logs:

```
2020-01-13T23:20:45.606166+00:00 app[web.1]: Average value = 0.09666666666666668
2020-01-13T23:20:45.607392+00:00 app[web.1]: New average values logged, industrial: 0.07
2020-01-13T23:20:45.607818+00:00 app[web.1]: New average values logged, milspec: 0.09666666666666668
2020-01-13T23:20:45.608896+00:00 app[web.1]: 0.09666666666666668
2020-01-13T23:20:45.608979+00:00 app[web.1]: No parse int: 0.096666666666666681
2020-01-13T23:20:45.609050+00:00 app[web.1]: ParseInt value: 0
2020-01-13T23:20:45.609102+00:00 app[web.1]: ParseInt + 1: 1
```

Comment: The value is a fraction, `parseInt` is for integers, so it ignores the fraction.

Comment: If you want to keep the fraction, use `parseFloat`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), it will truncate the integer without rounding it, so it essentially converts to `0`.

For rounding, you can use [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor), [`Math.ceil`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) or [`Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round), which rounds to the closest of them.

If precision is important, you can use the [`.toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method on numbers. Example:

```js
(0.12311).toFixed(2) // yields "0.12"
```

But it will convert to string. So to keep precision while still dealing with numbers, use [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat). Example:

```js
parseFloat((0.12311).toFixed(2)) // 0.12, this time as a number you can operate on
```

Comment: Thanks! That works great! Really appreciate the help!